# How to set up a Dockerfile so that the container OS will be Ubuntu?

Tags: docker, .net-core

I'm just getting into Docker, so please excuse my noobiness.

I've set up a Dockerfile for a unit testing project, based on the guidelines in [this article](https://techblog.dorogin.com/running-and-debugging-net-core-unit-tests-inside-docker-containers-48476eda2d2a). The container runs fine, and I managed to run the tests. But I got different results in my local container than we got on our build bot. So I thought it might be because the build bot is on Ubuntu, while my local container appears to be Debian.

So, how do I set up the Dockerfile to use Ubuntu rather than Debian?

Dockerfile code:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk
WORKDIR /src
COPY ./bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/linux-x64/publish/ .
ENTRYPOINT ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

Comment: Can you give some more details about what is different? It's a little vague at the moment.

Comment: @Dimitar FWIW, the difference is in the character encoding. Oh, and on the build bot, it's being built locally, whereas for my Docker container I'm building under Windows (for Linux) and copying over...shoot, I guess that pollutes my test anyway. (facepalm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the first line to the following:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1.302-sdk-bionic
```

Looking at its Dockerfile, it's built on an image that's built from a Ubuntu 18.04 image, so it's what you're looking for.